Telerik ASP.NET Core dateinput format in template not working
When I use DateInput as a component in a template and try to accept only the year part by setting the format to ("yyyy"), it doesn't work:
Html.Kendo().Template().AddComponent(btn => btn
                .DateInput()
                .Name("btn2_${data.Id}")
                .Format("yyyy")

Same scenario works when using ASP.NET Core MVC HTML helper.
<div>this works</div>
@Html.Kendo().DateInput().Name("thisworks").Format("yyyy")

Test:
https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/QeYTwWOd00v44FVm02

I was expecting input box to display year component of the date only.
